# Is it currently possible to cross compile SWIFT for another platform

Tags: cross-platform, llvm, swift

Because of LLVM will it be possible to actually compile SWIFT code for use on another platform.

Of course you couldn't use the Apple only libraries, but just for generic code, does LLVM enable this, even if Apple wouldn't support it?

Comment: I doubt this can be answered with more than speculation at this point. My guess would be no

Comment: That depends entirely on whether Apple's implementation will be open source and if not, how exactly it uses LLVM.

Comment: Even if Apple plans to open up their implementation, it probably won't be until Xcode 6, and by extension the Swift language come out of Beta

Comment: Why is this "opionion based"? The answer is just we won't know anything until Xcode 6 is out of beta.

Comment: Even if Apple won’t open-source their implementation, anyone can create a new one.

Comment: WTF!? ... how is this question "opinion" based? either there is a solution, or there is not ... closing this question means, that it has to be asked again after time passed by.